# How does the vimwiki ftplugin work?

Tags: vim

vimwiki has an ftplugin script file with name 'vimwiki.vim', 
 
and vimwiki file is named by *.wiki, but in the vim's help doc, 
ftplugin script only works for
<filetype>.vim 
<filetype>_xxx.vim
<filetype>/xxx.vim;
then how does the vimwiki.vim works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are mistaking filetype and extension. They are not equal, first is set in various ftdetect plugins that look like

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.text            setf text
```

(above is from `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`). This works because there is somewhere a command that sets filetype `vimwiki` for files that match `*.wiki`. Though for most files filetype can be guessed based on extension, ftdetect plugins can also use shebang or analyze file contents.

Comment: you are right, in vimwiki.vim, I have found out a line "set filetype=vimwiki", I think that's the magic. Thanks a lot.